# UIPageViewcontrollers, childcontroller button tapped events not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uipageviewcontroller

I have a uipageviewcontroller in which i have added a childview controller.The uipageviewcontroller scrolls in horizontal direction,the child view controller has six buttons but none of the tap events are working.is it because of some property from UIPageViewcontroller?

Comment: can you show some code how you create the child view controller the buttons and etc?

Comment: You can implement UIPageViewController with UICollectionview, you can handle it easily.